# How to use T4MVC with StructureMap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, structuremap, t4mvc

How to use T4MVC with StructureMap?

I've used T4MVC to kill the magic strings in my application. T4 generated some classes to handle that. I need to use StructureMap with these generated classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StructureMap and T4MVC are mostly orthogonal technologies, so using them on the same app should not be much different from using them separately.

If you are running into a specific issue while attempting to use them in the same app, please add more details to your question.